# Негоже или не гоже? Какая это часть речи?

Tags: орфография, частица-не

На одном из форумов был дан **такой ответ**: Правильный вопрос "Как?" и ответ на него в вопросе! Слово "негоже" отвечает на вопрос "как?" Пишется слитно! наречие ―  часть речи.

И никаких сомнений! Чем-то огорчили меня и эта уверенность, и такой уровень знания. Однако словарь на Грамоте.ру подтвердил слитное написание "негоже", дополнительно указав на вторую (предиктивную) функцию слова: **НЕГОЖЕ**, нареч. Нар.-разг. 1. к Негожий. Ведёшь себя н.! 2. в функц. сказ. Не следует, нельзя; не годится. Н. так говорить.

**Но раздельная форма тоже используется достаточно часто.**

1) **Пословицы:** Дай-то, Боже, чтобы все было **гоже**. На тебе, боже, что мне **не гоже**.

2) **Из Нацкорпуса:**

Соседка укорила ее: мол, **не гоже** в святой день за угощение деньги брать. [Ю. М. Нагибин. Дневник (1982)]   Нет, брат, так оно **не гоже**. [Ю. П. Герман. Россия молодая. (1952)]   «Что ты, ― говорят, ― боже, куда это **гоже**, чтоб незаробленное брать! [П. П. Бажов. Далевое глядельце (1946)] Этак не долго и обидёть людей-то… **Гоже** ли будет?.. [В. Я. Шишков. Емельян Пугачев. (1939-1945)]

**Так как же правильно выбрать и объяснить форму написание НЕ? Точно ли слитная форма имеет преимущество перед раздельной?**

Answer (score 2):

Слово ГОЖЕ (хорошо)устаревшее наречие, которое часто употреблялось в роли сказуемого (годится). То же, что годѣ:поклоно ѿ подвоискаго ко ѳилипу нь пожали г<ос>подине про сигы ѣще сигово нету поцта тобь буде гъже аѩзо тобе кланѩюсѩ

В украинском языке закрепилось как нейтральное слово, а в русском как просторечие или южный диалект.

От него наречие негоже -  нехорошо, неприлично, предосудительно,зазорно; в знач. сказ. негоже -  не следует, не подобает.

Если возьмём Даля, у него как раз народные, разговорные варианты:

Гоже не гоже, а на гоже-то похоже. На себя похоже, так гоже. Дай, Боже, чтобы все было гоже!

Нам не гоже, так вот тебе, Боже! - отрицание качества ГОЖЕ, а при отрицании положительного качества пишется раздельно (Хорошо - не хорошо, а делай)

Не гоже в крапиву садиться. На тебе, небоже, что мне не гоже. Большой толково-фразеологический словарь Михельсона (оригинальная орфография) - Старая орфография, отрицание того, что гоже.

Современный толковый словарь русского языка Ефремовой

1.Негоже-разг., наречие, свойство по значению.прилагательного негожий; плохо, дурно, нехорошо ◆ Ведёшь себя негоже!◆ Товарища выдавать негоже. А. Пантелеев, «Ленька Пантелеев», 1938-1952 г. ◆ Второй размер, отметил я, и тут же устыдился: негоже это ― переводить совершенство в номера и сантиметры. Е. А. Прошкин, «Механика вечности», 2001 г. (цитата из Национального корпуса русского языка, см. Список литературы)

2.В функции сказуемого неподходяще, не следует, нельзя, не годится ◆ То, что годится для иностранного словаря, газете — негоже. В. В. Маяковский ◆ Торопиться было негоже: кто-нибудь мог увидеть. С. Д. Мстиславский, «Грач — птица весенняя», 1937 г. (цитата из Национального корпуса русского языка, см. Список литературы) ◆ И ты встань, Петрок, негоже ползать перед ними на коленях. В. В. Быков, «Знак беды», 1982 г.

Так что и наречие (как?), и предикатив (каково?) пишется в соответствии с современными правилами - можно заменить синонимом - плохо, нельзя. А слова гоже нет, оно устарело, так что раздельного написания тоже нет, осталось только в народных пословицах.

Answer (score 1):

**гожий**, *арх., диал.*, кратк. **гоже**. – Годный, пригодный, правильный, подходящий. - ***Не гоже*** глаголишь;
**гожий**, кратк. **гоже, гожа** - «годный, пригодный, трудоспособный».
*Историко-лингвистический словарь трилогии «Государева вотчина» / Сибирский федеральный университет. – Красноярск. А.М.Бондаренко . 2007.*

ГО́ЖИЙ -ая, -ее; гож, -а, -е. обычно кратк. *Трад.-нар.* = Го́дный. - На тяжёлую работу не гож. И лесная рябина после мороза гожа.
*Энциклопедический словарь. 2009.*

Родственные слова:  негожий (прил.), негоже (наречие).
Думаю, что **не гоже** - краткое прилагательное с отрицанием, имеющее функцию предикатива, - для оценки характеристики ситуации, чьих-либо действий:

**Неудобья. Многодетным в Ульяновской области дают «что мне не гоже»?**
*Никита Гуляев, Еженедельник "Аргументы и Факты" № 18 29/04/2015*

**-Нет, - возразил Коле Родя, - откладывать не гоже.**
*А.Константинов, А.Новиков,  "Расследователь: предложение крымского премьера"*

P.S. В словаре русского языка (1957) в разделе *негоже* поговорка пишется так:
 *На тебе, боже, что нам **негоже.***

Comment: Римма, Вы же сами написали, что это архаизм и диалект, поэтому и раздельное написание - для архаичных выражений, а спрашивают о современных, в современном значении осталось только наречие и краткое прилагательное как разговорное, значит, слитно, ведь краткое прилагательное пишется так же, как и полное - негожий- негожее-негоже, а вот гожий уже нет, значит, и раздельного написания нет.

Answer (score 0):

**Спасибо всем за ответы, я попробую подвести итог.**

Из словаря Кузнецова:

**ГОЖИЙ**, -ая, -ее; гож, -а, -е. обычно кратк. Трад.-нар. =Годный. На тяжёлую работу **не гож**. И лесная рябина после мороза **гожа**.

**НЕГОЖИЙ**, -ая, -ее. Нар.-разг. =Негодный.

Формы краткого прилагательного: негожий, негож, негожа,негоже, негожи.

**Итак прилагательное "гожий" образует** антоним "негожий", имеет все краткие формы: **гож, гоже, гожи, негож, негоже, негожи,** образует обстоятельственное наречие "**негоже**" и предикативные формы (слова категории состояния) **гоже, негоже, не гоже**.

**Проблема написания НЕ связана именно с предикативом**, который может иметь две формы: **не гоже и негоже**. Выбор делается как обычно (по структуре, по авторской расстановке ударений), для сравнения:  **Нетрудно** видеть, что поезд Эйнштейна является именно "машиной времени". Ах, **не трудно** угадать мне вора, я его узнала по глазам.

**Вывод:**

1) Вся лексика, связанная со словами гожий, негожий находится в **активном запасе**, но имеет стилевые пометки (нар.-разг., трад.-нар.).

2) Этом могут быть **различные части речи:** полное и краткое прилагательное, обстоятельственное и предикативное наречие.

3) **Колебания в написании НЕ имеют только предикативные наречия**, замена близким синонимом проблемы в этом случае не решает.

Comment: Не совсем так. " Гоже - народно-традиционное" - это как раз и есть указание, что употребляется только в старых народных пословицах и исторических книгах, это не активный запас, архаизм. К пассивному запасу относятся устаревшие слова и неологизмы

Comment: А у  Вас есть точные  определения для этих стилевых пометок (трад.-нар., нар.-разг.), не поделитесь информацией. И по поводу пословиц, их всего 2-3 наберется, а в остальном обычная народная речь. И когда эти слова устарели? Весь 20-й век активно употреблялись, да и в современной речи встечаются. Загляните для интереса в Нацкорпус   http://search2.ruscorpora.ru/search.xml?env=alpha&mycorp=&mysent=&mysize=&mysentsize=&mydocsize=&dpp=&spp=&spd=&text=lexform&mode=main&sort=gr_tagging&lang=ru&nodia=1&req=%E3%EE%E6%E5